Error running 'app' Unexpected end of asynchronous channel
Tried building a sample app in Android Studio  and got the following error
Error running 'app'
Unexpected end of asynchronous channel

I tried both in the simulator and phone through a USB Cable.

I have followed this Answer but still getting this error.
